# Join Row to Previous Closest Date Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Database data:

```
id | account | date       | random_data
1  | 1       | 01/01/2013 | qw
2  | 2       | 05/01/2013 | er
3  | 2       | 09/01/2013 | ty
4  | 1       | 05/01/2013 | ui
5  | 2       | 11/01/2013 | op
6  | 1       | 12/01/2013 | as
```

Hi, so let's say I want the records starting from 05/01/2013 - note that prev_date for the 1st row still shows an earlier date than 05/01 meaning that the whole table still needs to be searched.

Result data:

```
account | cur_date   | random_data | prev_date  | prev_rand_data
1       | 05/01/2013 | ui          | 01/01/2013 | qw
1       | 12/01/2013 | as          | 05/01/2013 | ui
2       | 05/01/2013 | er          | null       | null
2       | 09/01/2013 | ty          | 05/01/2013 | er
2       | 11/01/2013 | op          | 09/01/2013 | ty
```

So I'm not sure what is the best, most optimized query I could use for this. I'm not opposed to a php solution but not sure how much better that would be. Some ideas I've considered:

1. Some sort of join on the same table - not sure how though
2. Sub queries on the select -

   `select date as cur_date
   , (select max(date) 
   from table 
   where date < cur_date 
   group by account) 
    as prev_date...` - this seems like it could be incredibly intensive
3. Session variables - set a session variable on each row which will be the previous data for the next row e.g.

   `select date as cur_date
   , @prev_date as prev_date
    , @prev_date:=date...`

Has anyone had any experience with a problem like this and was there a good solution? Are there any positives negatives with any of the ideas I have that could cause problems in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of sql and application code.  Since I am not a php programmer, I will only describe the logic to use for the application part.

First the query.

```
select account, date, random_data
from thetable
where date >= YourDateVariable

union

select account, date, random_data
from thetable join
(select account acc, max(date) maxdate
from thetable
where date <= YourDateVariable
group by account) x on account = acc and date = max(date)
where date <= YourDateVariable

order by account, date
```

For the application code, do this:

```
Set a variable called ThisAccount to 0.
Set a row counter variable to 0.
Create an empty 2D array
Start looping through your query results
Put the account value and random data into the first two columns
    of the next available row of the array
Compare the account value to the value of the ThisAccount variable.  
   If they are the same, get the previous date and random data from 
   the previous row in the array.
Set the ThisAccount variable to the current account value.
Increment your row counter variable
End of loop.
```